# How to configure OpenEdx LMS in Django?

Tags: django

I need to develop a LMS in Django with OpenEdx, but I don't know how to configure OpenEdx with Django.

Can anyone please help me to do this?

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Installation of all Open edX platform?

Answer (score 2):

OpenEdX is already built on django. To configure openedx on you local machine you need to start with devstack. [Here](https://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/installation/installation_options.html) is the guide to configure openedx.